# Get rid of strange inner shadow html5 video

Tags: html, video, styles, shadow

This might be a stupid question but i just cant get my head around it.
Can somebody tell me how i can get rid of this inner shadow. For some reason this is the default styling but i havent found out what it is exactly. And thus i dont know how to remove it. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do a search in your css for `box-shadow: inset` and you'll probably find your culprit pretty quickly. However without seeing your stuff I wouldn't be able to tell you where exactly. Just right-click it and choose "inspect element" to get the style(s) it's inheriting and start there.

Comment: Thats the thing, either i am simply not seeing it or there is no box-shadow in my stylesheet.
Also changing the box-shadow property in css  doesnt do much.

The code is just a simple 
<video>
<src>
</video>

Comment: Hmm, well it has to either be attached to `video` tag directly or on a parent element's css of where the video is embedded. Either that or it's unique to the video or maybe wherever you're feeding it from? That's about all I'd know, sorry.

Comment: Yes ! It's in the video. I guess something did go wrong while editing. 
Sorry for wasting your time haha but thanks for the help.